# constexpr array and std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time, initializer-list, constexpr

I was trying to write an compile-time valarray that could be used like this:

```
constexpr array<double> a = { 1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.3, 5.4, 6.5 };

static_assert(a[0] == 1.0, "");
static_assert(a[3] == 4.3, "");

static_assert(a.size() == 6, "");
```

I managed to do it with the following implementation and it works fine (with GCC 4.7):

```
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T>
struct array
{
    private:

        const std::size_t _size;
        const T* _data;

    public:

        constexpr array(std::initializer_list<T> values):
            _size(values.size()),
            _data(values.begin())
        {}

        constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t n)
            -> T
        {
            return _data[n]
        }

        constexpr auto size() const
            -> std::size_t;
        {
            return _size;
        }
};
```

Even though it works fine for me, I am not sure about the behaviour of `std::initializer_list` and may use some that are undefined behaviour.

`constexpr` for `std::initializer_list` constructor, `begin` and `size` is fine even though it is not strictly speaking C++11 since N3471 recently got adopted and made it to the standard.

Concerning the undefined behaviour, I am not sure whether the underlying array of the `std::initializer_list` will live or if not, whether there is a mean to have it live longer than only `array's` constructor. What do you think?

**EDIT:** I may not have been clear, but I do not really care about the actual array. What really interests me is the behaviour of `std::initializer_list` and its underlying array at compile-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current code *should not compile* according to current C++11 rules. When [compiled with clang 3.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3TRNX4%247) I get the following error:

```
source.cpp:33:28: error: constexpr variable 'a' must be initialized by a constant
expression 
constexpr array<double> a = { 1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.3, 5.4, 6.5 };
                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is because `std::initializer_list`s ctors and member functions `begin` and `end` are not labeled `constexpr`. However, [there already is a proposal to change this](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3471.html). BTW, libstdc++ already marks these as `constexpr`.

Now the next problem is the **lifetime** of the underlying array of `std::initializer_list`. This is explained in 8.5.4p6:

> The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object (12.2),
>   except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array
>   extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to
>   a temporary.

This means that the underlying array has the same lifetime as `values` object, and expires at the end of your `array` constructor when it exits. Therefore, `_data` is pointing to expired memory and `_data[n]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I could not find the revelant part of the standard about the lifetime :)
I already knew for `constexpr`, that's why I talked about N3471 which no only got proposed but also got accepted.