# Compile-time matrix template type

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to get a piece of code I am writing for fun working. Basically I'd like to generate a **type**, given at compile time: a matrix.

For instance, I'd like an `abstract_matrix` be something like the following:

```
template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c, class T = double>
class abstract_matrix
{
public:

    static const std::size_t rows = r;

    static const std::size_t cols = c;

    typedef T value_type;

    typedef T storage_type[rows][cols];

    constexpr abstract_matrix(storage_type items)
    {
        // I hope it's not needed
    }

    storage_type storage;
};
```

Then, I'd like to actually **create** concrete types with some magic, along the lines of these:

```
constexpr static const int vals[3][3] {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};

// do magic here for the vals parameter to make this compile
using id_3by3 = abstract_matrix<3, 3, vals, int>;

// use the generated type
id_3by3 mymatrix;

auto matrix = mymatrix * ...;
```

Do you have any suggestions about how to "*inject*" those values into the template and generate a proper type at compile time? Everything in the type is `static`, `const`, and `constexpr`.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the values of the matrix to be part of its type? Why? Why not simply `abstract_matrix<3, 3, int> id_3by3(vals);`?

Comment: You don't want to pass the `vals` in the template argument list. Look at `std::initializer_list`. It presents some issues with `constexpr`, though they are potentially being fixed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937522/constexpr-array-and-stdinitializer-list .

Comment: Yes, you don't *really* want the element values to be part of the type, as that will quickly lead to unimaginable volumes of template bloat, for no reason that I can imagine, or perhaps even just crash your compiler once you get beyond a certain dimension. Perhaps you should explain *why* you *think* you want this, so that you can get more useful answers that 'don't do that'.

Comment: @underscore_d, I doubt it will lead to bloated code. Not all the values of the `vals` array become part of the template definition. Only the address of `vals` becomes part of the template definition.

Comment: @RSahu That seems like an assumption to me, stemming from the vagueness of the question. My assumption just happened to be different.

Comment: @underscore_d, I made that statement based on my answer.

Comment: @RSahu And here I was thinking comments on the question should be about the question, not some answer. While the question is vague, it's fair to speculate that the OP might not really want what they think they want, and why that might be.

Comment: There is no particular reason about this, just learning compile-time options that I can have at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work but there are several things that must be considered.

1. `vals` can be passed as a non-type parameter. However, it needs to come after `T`. Otherwise, the fundamental type of the parameter is not known.

   As a consequence, there is no default value of `T`. You could potentially continue to have default value of `T` as `double` and default value of the last argument as `nullptr` but that leads to messy code.
2. Definition of `id_3by3` needs to use `&vals`, not just `vals`.
3. If you define `vals` to be `const`, then the non-type template parameter must also use `const` in its type.

   ```
   const int vals[3][3] { ... };
   ```

   mandates that you use

   ```
   template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c, class T, T const(*v)[r][c] >
   class abstract_matrix { ... };
   ```

   If you would like to be able to modify the contents of the matrix, you need to use:

   ```
   template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c, class T, T (*v)[r][c]>
   class abstract_matrix { ... };
   ```

   which mandates that you use

   ```
   int vals[3][3] { ... };
   ```

---

Here's a working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c, class T , T (*v)[r][c]>
class abstract_matrix
{
public:

    static const std::size_t rows = r;

    static const std::size_t cols = c;

    typedef T value_type;

    constexpr static T(&vals)[r][c] = *v;

    constexpr abstract_matrix()
    {
    }
};

int vals[3][3] {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};

using id_3by3 = abstract_matrix<3, 3, int, &vals>;

int main()
{
   id_3by3 mymatrix;

   // Original matrix.
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < id_3by3::rows; ++i )
   {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < id_3by3::cols; ++j )
      {
         std::cout << id_3by3::vals[i][j] << " ";
         id_3by3::vals[i][j]++;
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
   }
   std::cout << "\n";

   // Modified matrix.
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < id_3by3::rows; ++i )
   {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < id_3by3::cols; ++j )
      {
         std::cout << id_3by3::vals[i][j] << " ";
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

2 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 2
```

---

**Update, in response to OP's commment**

You can put use `static int vals[3][3] = { ... };` when you want to be able define the type a .h file and use it in multiple .cpp files.

I was able to use a .h file with the following content in multiple .cpp files.

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c, class T , T (*v)[r][c]>
class abstract_matrix
{
   public:

      static const std::size_t rows = r;

      static const std::size_t cols = c;

      typedef T value_type;

      constexpr static T(&vals)[r][c] = *v;

      constexpr abstract_matrix()
      {
      }
};

static int vals[3][3] {
   { 1, 0, 0 },
   { 0, 1, 0 },
   { 0, 0, 1 }
};

using id_3by3 = abstract_matrix<3, 3, int, &vals>;
```

That can still be improved by dividing those lines into two .h files. E.g., you could use:

abstract_matrix.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c, class T , T (*v)[r][c]>
class abstract_matrix
{
   public:

      static const std::size_t rows = r;

      static const std::size_t cols = c;

      typedef T value_type;

      constexpr static T(&vals)[r][c] = *v;

      constexpr abstract_matrix()
      {
      }
};
```

id_3by3.h:

```
#include "abstract_matrix.h"

static int vals[3][3] {
   { 1, 0, 0 },
   { 0, 1, 0 },
   { 0, 0, 1 }
};

using id_3by3 = abstract_matrix<3, 3, int, &vals>;
```

That will allow you to define other types similar to `id_3by3` in different .h files without needing to duplicate the definition of `abstract_matrix` in all of them.

Comment: Awesome! How can I avoid having multiple symbols definitions if I put this in my headers? I've tried static, const, constexpr, and different combinations, but either I cannot compile it (non type template parameter) or I have multiple definitions and so linker errors.

Comment: Thanks! The only warning I would give about this code is that, at least for me, it compiles with C++17 and above.

Comment: @senseiwa. that's strange. I was able to build the program using g++/C++11.