# Get number of constexpr initialized members of std::array

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm initializing an std::array at compile time with an initializer list, and I would like to have a way to store the number of elements. `std::array::size()` would return the size of the whole array and it's not what I'm looking for.

How could I improve the below code? Many thanks!

```
#include <array>

constexpr std::array<int, 5> a{{1, 2, 3}};

constexpr size_t element_count(const std::array<int, 5> &a) { return ???; }

int main() { static_assert(element_count(a) == 3); }
```

I'm compiling with `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`.

Comment: François, please see my answer to SergeyA's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this nicely in C++14. The type of the array is fixed in it's declaration, and it remains the same regardless of number of elements actually initialized to non-zero values.

In C++17 you would just do

```
std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

But in C++14 you'd have to use `auto` variable and `make_array` type of function. If you want, I can show example code.

P.S. As a matter of fact, lack of automatic array length deduction with `std::array` was the sole reason I was using C-style arrays in some of my code.

Comment: I see. But why is it available at runtime, if I iterate with for(auto& i : a){}? How does the for loop know when to stop?

Comment: @MihaiGalos It'll iterate over all 5 elements regardless.

Comment: Thank you, I think this explains all. No need for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible workaround by using a pointer to an initializer list begin and asking for its size at compile time: [constexpr array and std::initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937522/constexpr-array-and-stdinitializer-list). This code compiles on the above mentioned compiler and I can use the size() and operator[] during runtime to get information from the array.